# How to change text highlight color of selected method in peek window in Visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I click on a function that declared in other file, Vscode show me a small window with declaration of that function.
For more details please see the below picture.

[image: orange background color for peek window]

I want to change background color of the function in that window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `peekViewEditor.matchHighlightBackground` in your settings JSON like so:

```json
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": { //optionally specify theme, or omit this to apply to all themes
      "peekViewEditor.matchHighlightBackground": "#ff0000"
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, I made it a bright red:

[image: example showing the background color changed to bright red]